# Visual Studio Build Event xml expanded

Tags: visual-studio, post-build-event

I am calling a tool in the post-build event to create MAML documentation. The tool has arguments that can be XML. The problem is that when I use xml in the post-build event, it is expanded:

```
my_tool "blah <codeInline>test</codeInline>"
```

is expanded to

```
my_tool "blah <codeInline xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">test</codeInline>"
```

which is a big issue because of the " added (plus I'm pretty sure that the xmlns is not the correct one here).

How can I prevent Visual Studio from creting the xmlns?

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable:

```
SET CODE_INLINE=codeInline
my_tool "blah <%CODE_INLINE%>test</%CODE_INLINE%>"
```

Note that the SET must not be put inside an IF / FOR / ... otherwise the variable won't hold anything.